# Regular Expression for First Name and Last Name in a single field

Tags: java, regex

I have a scenario where user has to enter its first Name and last name in a single field, so there must be a space between 2 names, and after space there must be atleast  a character. I tried to using `contains("")`, but this method returns true if user just enter a space and does not enter anything after that space.

Kindly guide me a way to achieve this. I have also tried to search `Regular Expression` but failed to find any.

Comment: yup, i want to put validation on this, if user has no enter a single letter after space, i will stop him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the regex and a test:

```
@Test
public void test_firstAndLastName_success() {
  Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)");
  Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher("FirstName  LastName");
  if (matcher.find()) {
    Assert.assertEquals("FirstName", matcher.group(1));
    Assert.assertEquals("LastName", matcher.group(2));
  } else {
    Assert.fail();
  }
}
```

The validation is the `matcher` returning `false` on `find`.

If you do not want to permit multiple spaces (`\s+`) then either remove `+` (which will still permit for a single tab) or replace it with a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String input = "first last";
    if (input.matches("[a-zA-Z]*[\\s]{1}[a-zA-Z].*")) {
        String[] name = input.split(" ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please input the valid name.");
    }
}
```

It will put first name and last name to array if:

- `[a-zA-Z]*` - input begins with characters;
- `[\\s]{1}` - contains **only one** space;
- `[a-zA-Z].*` - ends with **at least** one character.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to put validation here, if user has not enter a single word after space, i will show him a  warning message

Answer (score 0):

A simple split using " " will do after trimming the string.

Please check the below code for more understanding :

```
String[] splitter = null;

String s = "abbsd sdsdf"; // string with 2 words and space

    splitter = s.trim().split(" ");

    if(splitter.length!=2){
        System.out.println("Please enter first or last name");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("First Name : "+splitter[0]);
        System.out.println("Last Name : "+splitter[1]);
    }

    s = "abc"; //string without space

    splitter = s.trim().split(" ");

    if(splitter.length!=2){
        System.out.println("Please enter first or last name");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("First Name : "+splitter[0]);
        System.out.println("Last Name : "+splitter[1]);
    }
```

Please check with other scenarios with and without space. This should be helpful.